# Query - Result is 0 when there is a math formula in the cell that is being queried

Tags: google-sheets

My issue is I am using query to pull from anther workbook. Everything is querying fine except the cells that contain a math formula, they are showing as 0
Example:
=I3-J3 or (Sum)I3-J3 is returning from the query as 0

Any help is greatly appreciated

Added note - if i type the result from the math formula it queries correctly

I have tried
Example:
=I3-J3 or (Sum)I3-J3 is returning from the query as 0

Comment: please share a sample sheet with example of the problem you have mentioned. You can recreate the problem in an [anonymous sheet](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScf4e8rJpjbDx-SQOH2c2xIaUP-ewnNJoqv9uRAXIrenUvZ_Q/viewform)

Comment: I have created the test sheet as asked. Odd thing, it works now. I noticed on my real sheet some are working and some are not. Its as if the query see the cell as blank. Sales Goal on the second tab is the one I am having issues with. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17PusFHBclyUYEf8wBLaXk3oX1if60WN0r_xr-IRbByY/edit?usp=drivesdk

Comment: the QUERY formula in the spreadsheet you have shared seems to be working fine. Which cell is not returning the expected result exactly?

Comment: also, you don't need to use IMPORTRANGE if you are importing the data from the same spreadsheet, you can simply use `'Main Page'!A1:AC`.

Comment: Its the 2nd Tab column H that does not work properly all the time. I used the IMPORTRANGE because on my sheet I have multiple sheets being queried. Its defiantly odd why the column (YELLOW) on the anonymous sheet does not work all the time. It was not working when I submitted this question but it is now.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.